# What does "tempering insight with compassion" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Among Scorpio's most important tasks, astrologers say, are ridding
>   themselves of the tendency to be judgmental and tempering their
>   insight with compassion.

What does "tempering insight with compassion" mean?

Comment: Have you looked up the verb *temper*? What did you find?

Comment: @StoneyB,thanx,I think I got it,it means that I have to fill my heart with compassion, I thought I have to get rid of compassion by tempering it .

Answer (score 4):

In materials science, tempering (speaking very broadly) takes a brittle substance (like glass or cold-rolled metal) and uses heating or cooling to impart more toughness (i.e., resistance to shattering).

The word has been borrowed in common usage to indicate the lessening or balancing of a harsh or unforgiving attribute.

In your case, an insightful Scorpio should "temper" their clever perceptiveness, which otherwise might lead them to judge harshly, with compassion.

Definition 9: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/temper

Read the "Word Origin and History" on that page for a bit more insight, including how the many meanings of temper all find their origin in the word's original use in material science.

Comment: I agree with your summary. "insight" does not need tempering. So I'm going to be harsh and judgmental and say that the quotation about the astrological sign is mush.